# testing yolov3 model getting cuda error >>no CUDA-capable device is detected: Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, darknet

I am getting this error while training yolov4 when I tried this code in google colab:
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map

Here is the error:

CUDA status Error: file: ./src/dark_cuda.c : () : line: 38 : build time: Feb  7 2022 - 05:58:34

CUDA Error: no CUDA-capable device is detected
Darknet error location: ./src/dark_cuda.c, check_error, line #69
CUDA Error: no CUDA-capable device is detected: Bad file descriptor

Can someone please help me

Comment: you might need CUDA for this task or change the parameter to use CPU instead

Comment: How do I install CUDA?

Comment: you can search on youtube